# No hyphenation patterns were loaded for the language

Tags: languages, hyphenation, babel

I'm using babel package for spanish language. However, each time I compile my document, the package babel throws me a warning:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel)                the language `Spanish'
(babel)                I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.
```

What goes?

Thank you...

Comment: According to google this is likly to be a bug in your TeX distribution. What operating system and TeX distribution are you using?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You may have to install spanish language support for TeX on your operating system. For instance, on Debian or Ubuntu it means to install `texlive-lang-spanish` I guess.

Afterwards it may be necessary to rebuilt the format files, for instance by

```
fmtutil --all
```

at the command prompt or the package manager of your TeX distribution.

I suggest you add some information to your question regarding operating system and TeX distribution.

However, this topic in the TeX FAQ may help you: [Using a new language with Babel](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-newlang). It deals with this warning message and shows ways how to fix that.

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu that command should probably be prefixed by a "`sudo `".

Comment: wow ok! thank you very much, that done it ...
sorry for not specifying everything... I use Debian Lenny, the TeX system is the one which comes by default there... mmm it is texlive, have I searched it ok? I'm kind of new with using TeX in a Linux box...

Comment: works like charm on ubuntu and solved my problems! Thanks!

Comment: Thank! I used synaptic to install "texlive-lang-spanish" and it works fine!

Comment: Perfect!!! I spent hours looking for a solution to this and finally I found this thread: "sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-spanish" did the trick!! :D Thank you so much!!

Comment: also works under mac OS with texlive installed via macports. The `fmtutil --all` was key there. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a clue what the MikTeX equivalent would be?

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue, but for german language. Instead of installing big collection-packages it was sufficient to install the package `hyphen-german` with TEX-Live Package Tool called `tlmgr`. For spanish language there is the package called `hyphen-spanish`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer for Ubuntu. Indeed, when you run `apt-cache show texlive-lang-spanish` you can see that is a collection of around 15 CTAN packages, and you do not need to clutter your computer by downloading all of them. Running `tlmgr install hyphen-spanish` should be enough.

Answer (score 12):

For Fedora, use `sudo dnf install texlive-hyphen-spanish`.

Comment: On future Fedora versions, remember to replace `yum` with `dnf` (`yum` is deprecated; at least on Fedora 23 the sistem does the replacement automatically, but don't count on it).

Answer (score 7):

For Fedora 24:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-babel-spanish texlive-hyphen-spanish
fmtutil --all
```

Comment: better to run also texhash after installing/modifying anything