# How to install a language package in Texmaker on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: languages, babel, ubuntu, texmaker

I'm having problems with the `babel` language package with TeXmaker could someone propose a fix I've typed in `\usepackage[french]{babel}`  and I get the following error:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel) the language "French"
(babel) I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.
\l@french = a dialect from \language0
```

I also have letters with accents show up as in the following screenshot (it's meant to be é â è) I'd assume I need to /usepackage but don't know which:

[image]

If someone could suggest a fix to these two problems, I'd be very grateful, I think I need to install a language package but I'm not sure how to go about that on Ubuntu 12.04 with TeXmaker and for the accents I don't know what package to use.

Comment: `sudo apt-get texlive-lang-french`; related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/no-hyphenation-patterns-were-loaded-for-the-language

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}`?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system help at all? It's the 'general case' answer for dealing with package installation on Linux.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Have you tried this in a terminal?

```
$ sudo apt-cache search texlive french
 texlive-doc-fr - TeX Live: French documentation
 texlive-lang-french - TeX Live: French

$sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-french
```

This example should work in a well installed TeX Live:

```
\documentclass[french,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\section*{L'histoire de la France au Moyen Âge}
L'histoire de la France au Moyen Âge se 
caractérise par plusieurs périodes et événements 
marquants durant dix siècles: de Clovis à 
Charles VIII, en passant par la fin de la 
Gaule romaine quand elle se détache de 
l'Empire romain, la guerre de Cent Ans, 
l'unification de la Gaule qui, au terme d'une
longue genèse, deviendra un État spécifique, 
le Royaume de France. Celui-ci apportera l'essor
 du christianisme, des campagnes, de la 
 population française, la renaissance 
 urbaine accompagnée par l'apparition 
 et l'affirmation des universités, la 
 formation de la langue française et 
 le développement du commerce (foires 
 et marchés).
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd forgotten to add that accents weren't working either, if you don't know how to solve that I'll accept your answer as it fixed my original problem and I'll post a separate question on accents.

Comment: @Oyibo, see the edited answer

Answer (score 3):

To solve the same issue for German:

> ngerman.sty not found

- For Ubuntu/Debian-based Distros:

install the `texlive-lang-german` package:

```
sudo apt install texlive-lang-german
```

- For Fedora/RHEL-based Distros:

install the `texlive-german` package and the `texlive-hyphen-german` package:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-german texlive-hyphen-german
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue for Spanish:

> Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for (babel)
>   the language "Spanish"

install the `texlive-hyphen-spanish` package:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-hyphen-spanish.noarch
```