# How to use foreign language in pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, babel, languages, ubuntu

I use `pdflatex` for my thesis which is written mostly in English. For that purpose I use `\usepackage[english]{babel}` in the preamble. However, I must provide also Czech version of the abstract. Even though the local characters are displayed well (such as "ěščř"), they can't be copied properly (after paste the result is "ˇeˇsˇcˇr").

Initially I tried `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` which lead to the following error:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `czech'. Either you misspelled it
(babel)                or the language definition file czech.ldf was not found.
```

What I intend to do is having the whole thesis in English style, i.e. using `\usepackage[english]{babel}` and mark my abstract as Czech like this:

```
\foreignlanguage{czech}{My long abstract...}
```

According to the first mentioned error, I assume that I haven't installed czech package yet (for pdflatex). I use Ubuntu.

```
$ apt-cache search latex czech
texlive-lang-czechslovak - TeX Live: Czech/Slovak
```

However, the `czechslovak` language option doesn't work either. So the questions: How to achieve previously described behavior? What to install? How to enable it?

Comment: As far as I know, the required package is named `babel-czech`.

Comment: `czech` works for me using TL on Linux. Usually, when you change the language a warning appears when you compile. Did you compile twice in a row?

Comment: `babel-czech` doesn't seem to exists (at least in standard ubuntu repository)...  @Sigur I compile twice, however it isn't a warning but an error

Comment: @petrbel, are you using TL from the repository or did you install it from the iso image?

Comment: After you install `texlive-lang-czechslovak` you should still do `\usepackage[czech]{babel}`, what else?

Comment: The common source of your copy-paste problem is the usage of bad fonts which implements the characters not directly, but via virtual fonts. For example T1 encoded fonts of Times, Helvetica etc. (Adobe 35) is this case. Because you don't provide the full minimal example, I cannot say more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First make sure you installed Tex Live properly, the command is

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Then you can try setting your document as utf-8 with `inputenc` (compiled with pdflatex).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,czech]{babel}

\begin{document}

This is some text in english.

\foreignlanguage{czech}{Český jazyk neboli čeština je západoslovanský jazyk, nejbližší slovenštině, poté polštině a lužické srbštině.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have `utf-8` set, thus the characters are displayed well. But it does not solve my problem with czech package that, apparently, is not present.

Comment: @petrbel How did you install the packages in Ubuntu? Did you do `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`?

Comment: I think you want `\usepackage[main=english,czech]{babel}` and the Czech part in a `\foreignlanguage`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann If he installed the packages, he should be able to do it without any use of tags.

Comment: @petrbel Try these questions (to see if they help): [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/4778) and [How to install a language package in Texmaker on Ubuntu 12.04?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73526/4778)

Comment: @Alenanno I was referring to your LaTeX coding, not to ubuntu packages

Comment: @AndrewSwann Ah, I misunderstood that. Would there be any differences? Maybe just in automatic commands like making the TOC or the like?

Comment: This affects (a) standard names for headings, (b) hyphenation and (c) shorthands.

Comment: @Alenanno after "full" isntallation everything works, thus thanks you :) maybe you could edit your answer in order to provide the comment information into the answer's body

Comment: @petrbel You mean `main=english`, I did, I was away from the keyboard for a few minutes. :D

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for the suggestion! Edited. But are the tags still needed?