# german.ldf not found

Tags: packages, german

I  use Texmaker and I used the assistant to start a new document. There I can choose some options, including a `babel`-package. I chose `german`, but when I compile the document, the compiler says

```
"Unknown option 'german'. Either you misspelled it (babel) or the language definition file german.ldf was not found".
```

I searched some internet platforms and documentations but didn't find an answer to my specific problem. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? Is there a possibility to install the `german`-package separately and if there is, how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is your distribution?

Comment: you need to have either TeX Live, MiKTeX or MacTeX installed on your computer depending on your operating system. TeXmaker is only the frontend/editor/IDE.

Comment: It is more likely that you want to try `ngerman` once the files are properly set up.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses. I know about ngerman, for some reason, Texmaker itself suggested the old german package. But it made no difference, both give the same problem.
I'm not sure, how to find out, what distribution I have, but my operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago, `babel` was split up in the base package and the languages.
Thus, you need to install `babel-german` (distribution package name in TeX Live or MiKTeX).

BTW, the option name for the German language after the orthography reform of 1996 is now `ngerman`. `ngerman.ldf` is also part of the distribution package `babel-german`.

Comment: How do I install that package? Can I just tell the computer to install it in the console, or do I have to go to a specific location in the program folder?

Comment: @Kathi Both TeX Live and MiKTeX come with documentation. Or if you had installed a different TeX distribution, that will also have some documentation very likely.

Comment: So, I found out, that I have TeX Live (it was already installed with my ubuntu version, so I only installed Texmaker). I looked through the documentation and I came across the package manager tlmgr. But when I tried to run some test commands I always get "cannot setup TLPDB in /home/kathi/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.".
I also tried to simply install babel-german and my computer said that the package couldn't be found.
I am not sure if this is a TeX-problem anymore or rather a Unix problem.

Comment: @Kathi According to [How to install a language package in Texmaker on Ubuntu 12.04?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73526/16967) the solution would be: `$ sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german`

Comment: I did install the package you mentioned using synaptic, which I found out is very helpful when searching for some package without exactly knowing the name. (A friend called coincidentally and told me just before I read your answer) So problem solved now, thank you!