# need a font for polytonic Greek

Tags: fonts, fontspec, greek

I'm using this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}
\setmainfont{Garamond}

\begin{document}

book title Περί τὴν ἄλωσιν τῆς Kωνσταντινουπόλες

\end{document}
```

and trying to write these greek characters ἄ ὴ ῆ. Can someone suggest a group of fonts that support them ?

Comment: @egreg I get (test_greek.aux) ! Undefined control sequence. l.9 book title \textgreek {Περί τὴν ἄλωσιν τῆς Kωνστα...

Comment: What you are showing are not just letters but letters with diacritics. The `betababel` package lets you input these letters with diacritics from a regular Latin-lettered keyboard. For an example, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389105/typeset-greek-words/389110#389110

Comment: Off-topic: If you're loading the `fontspec` package, you shouldn't be loading the `inputenc` package as well.

Comment: Just delete `test_greek.aux` and recompile the LaTeX following egreg's instruction. Your first attempt will have put some rubbish in the .aux file which will keep generating fatal errors.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer - Are you sure the link you provided in the comment is relevant to the OP's issue? It would appear that the OP has already mastered the art of inputting (Greek) letters with various diacritics.

Comment: Off topic: "της Κωνσταντινουπόλεος"

Comment: @Mico - yes, I am sure. Greek uses a whole lot more diacritics than the Latin alphabet does. The betababel package constructs all these composite characters from the basic ones by adding diacritics.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer - You may want to post a separate answer, illustrating how to make use of the `betababel` package to meet the OP's typesetting needs (which include use of the `fontspec` package and utf8-encoded input).

Comment: @Mico -  I regularly get flack for answers promoting betababel, usually from people who don't know Greek and think that Unicode Is The Answer To Life, the Universe, and Everything.

Comment: @koleygr thanks, that seems to be indeed the title.

Comment: I also have turkish letters so more answers are welcome.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer - Ignore the flack, and just post an answer that *you* find is relevant and helpful. I long ago learned to shrug off the occasional downvote on my answers, especially when it's an anonymous downvote. I do like to take constructive criticism seriously, though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're interested in using Garalde-type text fonts. If so, the free-of-charge `Cardo` and `EB Garamond` font packages should be of interest to you. The `Cardo` font is, AFAICT, not distributed with TeXLive; it may be downloaded from [the font creator's own website](http://scholarsfonts.net/cardofnt.html). `EB Garamond` is distributed automatically with TeXlive (and  with MikTeX too, I believe).

Other font packages you may want to consider -- even though they're not true Garaldes -- are `CMU Serif`, `GFS Artemisia`, `GFS Bodoni`, `GFS Didot`, `Junicode`, `Linux Libertine O`, and `Old Standard`. (I'm drawing heavily on [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127222/5001) and especially egreg's answer for the preceding list.) Depending on your operating system, further suitable system fonts may be available. E.g., if you use MacOSX and MacTeX, you could consider using `Garamond Premier Pro`, `Arno Pro`, and `Minion Pro`. Naturally, there's also a huge number of commercial fonts that might satisfy your font-related needs.

By the way, if one uses XeLaTex or LuaLaTeX along with the `fontspec` package, one should *not* load the `inputenc` package. XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX can handle only one input font encoding anyway: `utf8`.

The following example was compiled under LuaLaTeX. To increase comparability, the fonts are scaled to have the same "x-heights" (via the `fontspec` option `Scale=MatchLowercase`). Some fonts are more "compressed" than others; there's also considerable variation in terms of "color", i.e., "darkness". The Greek characters of `Junicode` may be too slanted for some tastes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase} % scale fonts to have same x-heights

\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\newcommand\teststring{book title Περί τὴν ἄλωσιν τῆς Kωνσταντινουπόλες}
\newcommand\test[1]{%
   \medskip\setmainfont{#1}#1\par\teststring}

\begin{document}    
\obeylines % just for this example

\test{Arno Pro Regular 10pt}
\test{Cardo}
\test{CMU Serif}
\test{EB Garamond}
\test{Garamond Premier Pro}
\test{GFS Artemisia}
\test{GFS Bodoni}
\test{GFS Didot}
\test{Junicode}
\test{Linux Libertine O}
\test{Minion Pro Medium}
\test{Old Standard}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thx mico. The code worked after I installed the font Cardo. I am still having some problems putting it in my main code.

Comment: I get an error in l.8 \setmainfont   {Cardo}  ?   while it compiles fine in another tex.

Comment: @alfred - Please be more specific about the error you're getting. (The statement "I get an error" is not exactly illuminating.)

Comment: I know, but it isnt giving me any more specifications. I'll look into it tomorrow and maybe post another question about it.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was, but I rebuild my main code and it's fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127224/5001), `Gentium Plus` might be another suitable font.

Comment: Also suitable: `Times New Roman`. Two suitable sans-serif font families are `Helvetica Neue` and `Linux Biolinum O`.

Comment: I'm still having problems installing some of the fonts. My system (W10x64-MiKTeX 2.9, Ghostscript 0.92, WinEdt 10.2) accepts Cardo, Junicode, Minion Pro Medium only, even if I installed Arno Pro Regular, Linux Libertine O, EB Garamond etc and restarted.

Comment: @alfred - You may want to post a new query, then, to ask how to install opentype fonts on a Windows-MikTeX2.9 system. You may also want to specify whether you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. FWIW, my system is a MacBookPro, MacOSX 10.13, MacTeX2017, LuaTeX 1.0.4. The fonts mentioned in my answer are either distributed with TeXLive (and presumably MikTeX too), MacOSX system fonts, or downloadable free-of-charge (Cardo). I'm a Mac-person through-and-through; I have very little experience with MikTeX, and I count every day that I don't have to touch a Windows machine as a special blessing. :-)

Comment: I'll try still for another hour or so before posting a new query. I used both XeLaTex and LuaLaTex, and I'm all windows :)

Comment: Minor typo: `MatchLowercase`, not `MathLowercase`.

Comment: @Davislor - Thanks! I've fixed the typo.

Comment: @campa - I'm afraid I am unable to replicate the issues you raise: No  warning messages of any kind, no falling back to CM. (I use LuaTeX1.07.0, LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5, MacTeX2018, and MacOS 10.13.6. I added `\par\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{>'alwsin}` to `\teststring` and re-ran the MWE.) Please be more specific about what you're doing.