How can I write greek letters in Latex in a fluent text
I try to write greek letters line by line in TeXstudio for later use with pdflatex. Unfortunately betababel is not recognized by TeXstudio. Has anyone a working example not using $\alpha$ , $\beta$ , $\gamma$ ?

If by "betababel is not recognized by TeXstudio" you mean this error in your non-answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729713/36296 then you probably haven't installed the the babel-greek package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540772/36296 how to install it.

If I understand your question, a simple example would be

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

Σύμφωνα με το google αυτό είναι κάποιο ελληνικό κείμενο.

\end{document}


Doing so I get:

peter@peter-969:~/rub/promo/diss$ pdflatex stOvEx.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./stOvEx.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (./lgrenc.def
(./greek-fontenc.def)) (./lgrcmr.fd)

kpathsea: Running mktextfm grmn1000
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input grmn1000
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)
kpathsea: Running mktexmf grmn1000
! I can't find file `grmn1000'.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input grmn1000
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input grmn1000
?

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: grmn1000.log: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input grmn1000' failed to make grmn1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
! Font LGR/cmr/m/n/10=grmn1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.

relax
l.112 ...\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault
?

main reason seems to be:

grmn1000.log: Dataset not found

@user3647093 you don't want to use bitmap (metafont) greek you want tpe1 scalable, the abov example should have a log showing /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cbfonts/grmn1000.pfb  or wherever your tex is installed/ you shoul dhave or be able to add cbfonts to texlive.

@user3647093 you are using debian texlive so probably sudo apt get texlive-lang-greek  is what you are missing see https://packages.debian.org/sid/texlive-lang-greek

Thank you so much, after 'sudo apt get texlive-lang-greek' the example works. But I mainly need german with some greek inserted. If I run my original document it is pure greek, how do I achieve the mix ?

@user3647093 make sure you have gernan installed via sudo (it's simpler to install everything at the start) then \usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[greek,ngerman]{babel} will define a document with main language German and Greek availabe via language switch commands, see babel manual

Hi David, everything is working fine now, thanks a lot. Using \textgreek and switching to my greek keybord I have all I need for my doctoral dissertation in ancient philology.  Greetings from Dortmund, Germany, have a nice day
