# How to reduce number of hyphenation patterns preloaded in MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, babel, hyphenation

MikTeX comes with 69 languages preloaded as reported at compilation time:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.11.9)  13 NOV 2015 10:35
entering extended mode
**PlasmaBook1.tex
("D:\Your files\KIA\OneDrive\PlasmaBook2\PlasmaBook1.tex"
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
```

I don't like this situation while cannot explain exactly why, perhaps, because in the past saving computer memory was a recommended practise.

I tried to remove unused languages though the **MikTeX Options**.

I unchecked most of languages on the Language tab:
[image]

and rebuilt all formats:

[image]

Nothing has changed. At compilation time I still saw

```
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
```

However running `initexmf --dump` from command prompt has actually removed unused languages. It seems that **MikTeX Options** has long-standing bug as was reported in [Language (hyphenation patterns) not available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83682/language-hyphenation-patterns-not-available) 2 years ago.

A minor question is which of 4 hyphenation patterns for German language available in MiKTeX is recommended for users who (as me) load German pattern only to cite references.

Comment: With initexmf --dump you are building user formats which are stored in your user profile. With miktex settings (admin) you are changing and building admin formats. As user formats are found first they win. Use the user version of miktex settings to change and build them through a GUI. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490?s=1|0.1749#108490

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, please make an answer from your comment in order I could accept it.

Answer (score 3):

With `initexmf --dump` you are building *user* formats which are stored in your user profile. With `miktex settings (admin)` (or `initexmf --admin --dump`) you are changing and building *admin* formats. As user formats are found first they win.

So use the *user*  version of `miktex settings` to change and build them through a GUI. See also [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490)

Comment: It is somewhat strange. I always install new package  and run **MikTeX Options** in admin modes. Why should I care about user's fmt? Why they appear at least? It's beyond any logics.

Comment: Well you *did* run `initexmf --dump` (and not `initexmf --admin --dump`) and so created user formats. Also it is possible that they appear on their own: After some updates the next pdflatex compilation can force the recreation of formats.

Comment: I usually launch MikTeX options from WinEdt 9 menu. It is tuned by default to use admin mode. How this behaviour could be changed?