# How to fix the warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for (babel) the language `Portuguese'?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, hyphenation

I am on Windows using this `MikTex`version:

```
pdflatex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6211 (1.40.17) (MiKTeX 2.9.6210)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2016 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.52.1; using libcurl/7.52.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020022; using 50020022
compiled with libpng version 1.6.28; using 1.6.28
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.4.4; using LibreSSL 2.4.4
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 1.6211; using 1.6211
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 1.6216; using 1.6233
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6211; using 1.6211
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6218; using 1.6229
compiled with poppler version 0.50.0
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.10; using 1.2.10
```

When I am compiling it, I am getting this boring warning:

```
D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf: 
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for(babel) 
the language `Portuguese' into the format.
```

This is my minimal example to trigger this issue:

```
% proposal.tex
% Based on http://www.latextemplates.com/template/simple-sectioned-essay
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{hyphsubst}
\usepackage{graphicx} % resizebox
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Riscos}

    A junção de agentes e realidade virtual, pode-se criar novos
    produtos de auxilio há indivíduos. Os agentes farão o trabalho de
    guiar o indivíduo, lhe mostrando exercícios e definições de um
    determinado assunto conforme seu nível de conhecimento, e a
    realidade virtual, proporcionando um nova experiência, onde é
    possível detalhar a explicação do corte de cônicas estudado em
    geometria analítica, por exemplo.

\end{document}
```

I spend hours searching and instaling a lots of stuff hope to get ride of it, but it just does not go away. Here I am listing all packages I got installed by the command `mpm --list` and getting all the lines with `i`:

```
i 00119     506513 ae
i 00027    1717404 amscls
i 00618    7714923 amsfonts
i 00025    2669600 amsmath
i 00257    7488486 arabi
i 00174    1224330 avantgar
i 00072    1620030 babel
i 00011     164011 babel-english
i 00005     383412 babel-french
i 00012     765427 babel-german
i 00003     159851 babel-portuges
i 00003      13418 babel-spanglish
i 00006     248833 babel-spanish
i 00017     635909 bibtex
i 00014     144398 bibtex8bit
i 00005      36515 bibtex8bit-polish
i 00148    5153378 bidi
i 00210    1389763 bookman
i 00011      64171 carlisle
i 00020     703910 catalan
i 00016     496287 cbcoptic
i 00002      24576 chktex
i 00012     223126 churchslavonic
i 00009     318992 cite
i 00325    3710497 cjk
i 00201     889884 cm
i 00840   68081483 cm-super
i 00128   29364389 cm-unicode
i 00014      33058 cmap
i 00031     388574 cmarrows
i 00018      71145 cmastro
i 00180    1066905 cmbright
i 00710    2489626 cmcyr
i 00010      31341 cmcyralt
i 00005     362208 cmdstring
i 00004     144467 cmdtrack
i 00026      64232 cmextra
i 00010     170298 cmfrak
i 00110     660888 cmll
i 00006      29026 cmpica
i 00012     826166 cmpj
i 00006       7089 cmsd
i 00082    1348007 cmtiup
i 00005     111287 combelow
i 00184    1258125 courier
i 00046     309082 croatian
i 00259     427180 csfonts
i 00042     117149 cslatex
i 00090    1610059 csplain
i 00002      27382 cweb
i 00119    1540549 cyrillic
i 00004     226487 dehyph
i 00013     590333 dehyph-exptl
i 00011     568289 dvipdfmx
i 00076     171333 dvips
i 00043    2124729 e-french
i 01233    2573583 ec
i 00011    1937013 elhyphen
i 00049     547873 enctex
i 00014     526673 etex
i 00003      20672 etex-pkg
i 00018     180439 euenc
i 00039     268300 eurosym
i 00004       3729 fahyph
i 00009     792145 fancyvrb
i 00007      61687 findhyph
i 00005     408447 fixltxhyph
i 00004     157534 float
i 00034      65485 fontconfig
i 00024    1509270 fontname
i 00018    2119120 fontspec
i 00005     374186 footmisc
i 00006     281484 geometry
i 00236    1264399 ghostscript
i 00010      40933 glhyph
i 00004     343243 gmverb
i 00035    2612687 graphics
i 00004       4638 graphics-cfg
i 00008     143924 graphics-def
i 00002       8598 gsftopk
i 00008     886014 he-le-na
i 00339    2456296 helvetic
i 00047    5445822 hyperref
i 00539    8732257 hyph-utf8
i 00004     192828 hyphenat
i 00007     115243 ibycus-babel
i 00004     169627 ifxetex
i 00020      39219 jknappen
i 00038     412797 kdgreek
i 00026     128912 knuth-lib
i 00028     147457 knuth-local
i 00055     123937 latex-fonts
i 00024     915384 latexmk
i 00053     208699 lhcyr
i 00069     424361 lithuanian
i 01093   43912172 lm
i 00207   12386523 ltxbase
i 00035     204707 ltxmisc
i 00006      10630 lua-alt-getopt
i 00009     132554 lua-check-hyphen
i 00005      46276 luahyphenrules
i 00010     443986 luainputenc
i 00042     704479 lualibs
i 00009     246501 luamplib
i 00098    5027490 luaotfload
i 00013     286569 luatexbase
i 00006     322823 luatextra
i 00013     421099 makeindex
i 00008     119377 metafont
i 00124    2902052 metapost
i 00011     253287 mex
i 00007     270547 mflogo
i 00019      41366 mflogo-font
i 00004      10421 mfware
i 00031    2451481 microtype
i 00003     156884 miktex-arctrl-bin-2.9
i 00003     225321 miktex-bibarts-bin
i 00002   23691765 miktex-biber-bin
i 00003     259829 miktex-bibtex-bin-2.9
i 00003     378122 miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-2.9
i 00005   28126073 miktex-bin-2.9
i 00002      79067 miktex-bzip2-bin-2.9
i 00002    1660570 miktex-cairo-bin-2.9
i 00002     111828 miktex-chktex-bin-2.9
i 00009     329671 miktex-cjkutils-bin-2.9
i 00062      42813 miktex-config-2.9
i 00002     408157 miktex-curl-bin-2.9
i 00003     232722 miktex-cweb-bin-2.9
i 00002      83173 miktex-devnag-bin-2.9
i 00007     583103 miktex-dict-english
i 00004    1392137 miktex-dict-french
i 00010    4347300 miktex-dict-german
i 00191    2693499 miktex-doc-2.9
i 00003     241921 miktex-dvicopy-bin-2.9
i 00003      10229 miktex-dvipdfmx
i 00003     822520 miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-2.9
i 00002     175009 miktex-dvipng-bin-2.9
i 00004       7611 miktex-dvips
i 00003     366818 miktex-dvips-bin-2.9
i 00002    5007596 miktex-dvisvgm-bin-2.9
i 00002     110292 miktex-epstopdf-bin-2.9
i 00002        710 miktex-etex
i 00002     148372 miktex-expat-bin-2.9
i 00002      95957 miktex-findtexmf-bin-2.9
i 00003      10349 miktex-fontconfig
i 00010     773632 miktex-fontconfig-bin-2.9
i 00005     368917 miktex-fonts-bin-2.9
i 00002     608221 miktex-freetype2-bin-2.9
i 00002     111845 miktex-fribidixetex-bin-2.9
i 00002     441009 miktex-gd-bin-2.9
i 00002   14569984 miktex-ghostscript-bin
i 00002     186039 miktex-graphite2-bin-2.9
i 00002     136390 miktex-gsf2pk-bin-2.9
i 00002     576956 miktex-hunspell-bin-2.9
i 00003   29286400 miktex-icu-bin
i 00004   21502283 miktex-int-bin-2.9
i 00002     300283 miktex-jpeg-bin-2.9
i 00002      67821 miktex-kpathsea-bin-2.9
i 00003        943 miktex-latex
i 00002    1433999 miktex-libressl-bin-2.9
i 00004    3188587 miktex-log4cxx-bin-2.9
i 00004     346436 miktex-lua52-bin-2.9
i 00004     137705 miktex-luatex
i 00004   17631837 miktex-luatex-bin-2.9
i 00002     173762 miktex-lzma-bin-2.9
i 00002     158097 miktex-m-tx-bin-2.9
i 00003     278302 miktex-makeindex-bin-2.9
i 00002      27368 miktex-md5-bin-2.9
i 00002        732 miktex-metafont
i 00003     499447 miktex-metafont-bin-2.9
i 00003        824 miktex-metapost
i 00002    2047138 miktex-metapost-bin-2.9
i 00009     645552 miktex-mfware-bin-2.9
i 00027     114790 miktex-misc
i 00002     214737 miktex-mkfntmap-bin-2.9
i 00006     660892 miktex-mktex-bin-2.9
i 00004     939783 miktex-mo-bin-2.9
i 00005     756552 miktex-mpm-bin-2.9
i 00002    6416125 miktex-mpmcli-bin-2.9
i 00002      92955 miktex-mspack-bin-2.9
i 00002     133319 miktex-mthelp-bin-2.9
i 00002     150734 miktex-mtprint-bin-2.9
i 00003        775 miktex-omega
i 00016    2124935 miktex-omega-bin-2.9
i 00006       2800 miktex-pdftex
i 00005    4446009 miktex-pdftex-bin-2.9
i 00003     660069 miktex-pmx-bin-2.9
i 00002     204628 miktex-png-bin-2.9
i 00013   22045268 miktex-poppler-bin-2.9
i 00002      57213 miktex-popt-bin-2.9
i 00003      99641 miktex-posix-bin-2.9
i 00002     176274 miktex-ps2pk-bin-2.9
i 00009     437207 miktex-psutils-bin-2.9
i 00011   19340288 miktex-qt5-bin
i 00021    4665814 miktex-runtime-bin-2.9
i 00002     214251 miktex-tdsutil-bin-2.9
i 00002     256235 miktex-teckit-bin-2.9
i 00003        842 miktex-tex
i 00003     560870 miktex-tex-bin-2.9
i 00002      68831 miktex-tex2xindy-bin-2.9
i 00002      13868 miktex-tex4ht
i 00003     237300 miktex-tex4ht-bin-2.9
i 00002     192199 miktex-texify-bin-2.9
i 00002        877 miktex-texinfo
i 00009     643523 miktex-texware-bin-2.9
i 00002    6913277 miktex-texworks-bin-2.9
i 00003     269089 miktex-ttf2pk2-bin-2.9
i 00042    1787762 miktex-ucrt-bin
i 00002      84354 miktex-uriparser-bin-2.9
i 00017    6547029 miktex-vc140-bin
i 00005     357628 miktex-web-bin-2.9
i 00002       3914 miktex-xetex
i 00003    2900223 miktex-xetex-bin-2.9
i 00002    5119516 miktex-xindy-bin
i 00004    2016241 miktex-yap-bin-2.9
i 00002     304800 miktex-zip-bin
i 00002     101275 miktex-zlib-bin-2.9
i 00002      41197 miktex-zzip-bin-2.9
i 00012      50417 mltex
i 00222    5000829 montex
i 00006     153202 mptopdf
i 00013    2614447 ms
i 00006     637728 multirow
i 00154     912870 ncntrsbk
i 00562   22030696 oberdiek
i 00245    1167385 palatino
i 00004     305952 path
i 00002     181083 pdftex
i 00011     105138 plain
i 00458    5090281 polish-doc
i 00115     955553 polyglossia
i 00251   12011866 poppler
i 00011      47671 pslatex
i 00119     540586 psnfss
i 00040    8804588 pstricks
i 00002       7157 psutils
i 00018     101828 rsfs
i 00027     223320 ruhyphen
i 00005     531798 russ
i 00015     763806 selnolig
i 00006     106984 showhyphens
i 00007     312496 soul
i 00003      15503 spanglish
i 00005     291172 sr-half-compound
i 00009     961652 sr-hyphen-spec
i 00005     395943 testhyphens
i 00032     117863 tetex
i 00010      11095 tex-ini-files
i 00027    1954420 texinfo
i 00006     436122 textglos
i 00012     676861 thailatex
i 00004      97442 thumbpdf
i 00239    1508359 times
i 00072    7079674 tools
i 00016     881891 ttf2pk
i 00023     328669 tui
i 00493    8647699 uk-tex-faq
i 00028     685133 ukrhyph
i 00004     270322 underscore
i 00011    2211998 unicode-data
i 00004     279266 url
i 00060     556968 utopia
i 00004      42334 varsfromjobname
i 00036     376531 xecyr
i 00008     392733 xetex
i 00005     104603 xgreek
i 00432    2616515 xindy
i 00022     630068 xkeyval
i 00005     148819 xltxtra
i 00003     207272 xunicode
i 00184    6003498 xypic
i 00036     326052 yannisgr
i 00031     175798 zapfchan
i 00010      70264 zapfding
i 00003       1494 zerohyph
i 04939    5792777 zhmetrics
```

To compile it I am using the plugin `LaTeX Tools` for Sublime Text.

But when I use directly the command line:

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make main.tex
```

I got the following error:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Portuguese' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 55.
```

How to fix this error? I am missing some package which is not installed?

This is image I got from the `mo.exe` latex program. It seems to have everything in place:

[image]

Comment: Try redoing the formats with MiKTeX Settings. Did you update recently? MiKTeX version is 6300 now.

Comment: I hope the example text in Portuguese is just filler text, because grammatically it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the question already has an accepted answer, I feel the urge to provide a solution which does not depend on luck with the update, for this did not work for me.

I had the same problem with German hyphenation and was eventually able to solve it. Maybe this helps future users to solve their problem.

**Setup**

Brand new TeX installation (MiKTeX, installed for single user, based on 'essential' package set).

Test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}Hello World!\end{document}
```

pdfLaTeX gave the infamous warning:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `German (new orthography)' into the format.
```

**1. Babel installed**

⯈ Verify that package `babel-german` is installed.

**2. Language installed**

⯈ Check with MiKTeX Console (or similar) if the language is installed (Settings >  Languages). For me, it was not. It showed `ngerman` and `ngerman-x-2019-04-04` with loader and package names, but did not state that those were installed. I wonder why. Not any of the languages was installed.

⯈ If the language is not installed, install `hyph-utf8` and `dehyph-exptl` or whatever file is mentioned for your language. Restart MiKTeX Console and verifiy that there is a check mark at both 'ngerman' rows.

**3. pdflatex.fmt**

⯈ (Obsolete if step 4 will be performed as well) (Re?)create the formats using `initexmf --dump=pdflatex` which will create/update `%localappdata%\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\data\le\pdftex\pdflatex.fmt`. You may omit the `=pdflatex` to let initex create *all* format files.

Weird: I could not find folders for any other key containing the corresponding format files. Apparently, my appumption was invalid and the installation of a language file does not trigger re-creation of the format files.

**4. language.dat**

⯈ Have a look at language.dat file at `%appdata%\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\config`. I found it absolutely empty. `language.dat.lua` contained just `return {}`, `language.def` contained `%% e-TeX V2.2`.

⯈ Fix (?) this with `initexmf --mklangs` which fills those files with content:

language.dat then contained

```
ngerman loadhyph-de-1996.tex
ngerman-x-2019-04-04 dehyphn-x-2019-04-04.tex
=ngerman-x-latest
```

and language.def contained

```
\addlanguage{ngerman}{loadhyph-de-1996.tex}{}{2}{2}
\addlanguage{ngerman-x-2019-04-04}{dehyphn-x-2019-04-04.tex}{}{2}{2}
```

and the referenced file `dehyphn-x-2019-04-04.tex` existed and had some probably useful content.

⯈ A new run of `initexmf --dump` updates the format files and finally, pdfLaTeX no longer complains.

**References**

[[TeX:SX]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365804/78593)
[[TeX-FAQ]](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-newlang)
[[SourceForge]](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/discussion/33790/thread/816aa923/#2b15)
[[GitHub]](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/108)

Comment: I am pretty new to Ubuntu and I could follow this recipe easily. Thank you very much. This made my day!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks [@Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908) I updated my `MikTex` installation now I am not noticing this warning anymore:

```
pdflatex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX  (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)

using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.53.1; using libcurl/7.53.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libpng version 1.6.29; using 1.6.29
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.4.5; using LibreSSL 2.4.5
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with poppler version 0.53.0
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

This is my recent compilation output, where I cannot notice anymore that warning:

```
make
latexmk -pdf -output-directory="cache" -aux-directory="cache" -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make main.tex
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017, version: 4.52c.
Latexmk: making output directory 'cache'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder -output-directory="cache"  "main.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
entering extended mode
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\size12.clo))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\utf8.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu)))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.def)))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hyphsubst.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty))))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\array.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.st
y
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\cite\cite.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\mathptmx.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype-pdftex.de
f) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.cfg))
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.aux)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\t1ptm.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\mt-ptm.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omlztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omsztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omxztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ptm.fd) [1{D:/User/
Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Terence' on page 1 undefined on input line 111.

...

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omsptm.fd) [4]
[5]
Underfull \hbox (badness 3769) in paragraph at lines 289--289
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Estudo da im-ple-men-ta-▒▒o de
[6] [7] [8] [9]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 392--403

[10] [11]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 424--424
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 424--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Manuten▒▒o

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Usar o la-

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--426
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Manuten▒▒o

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 426--426
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 2012) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas de

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Tratamento

Underfull \hbox (badness 1953) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Cuidados di▒-

Underfull \hbox (badness 5637) in paragraph at lines 427--427
\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) rios apro-pri-a-
[12]
No file main.bbl.

(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information){D:/User/Documents/latex/te
xmfs/install/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/instal
l/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/ins
tall/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/f
onts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/t
ype1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on D:\ObjectBeautif
ier\monograph\proposal\cache\main.pdf (13 pages, 77924 bytes).
Transcript written on D:\ObjectBea
utifier\monograph\proposal\cache\main.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'cache/main.bbl'
 No file main.bbl.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'cache/main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
...
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [refs.bib]
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'cache/main.bbl' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "cache/main.bbl"'
------------
make[1]: Entering directory '/monograph/proposal'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'cache/main.bbl'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/monograph/proposal'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 11 citation(s)
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex cache/main'...
Rule 'bibtex cache/main': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'cache/main.aux'
   Non-existent destination files:
      'cache/main.bbl'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'bibtex cache/main'
------------
For rule 'bibtex cache/main', running '&run_bibtex(  )' ...
------------
Running 'bibtex  "main"'
------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: abbrv.bst
Database file #1: refs.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'cache/main.aux'
      'cache/main.bbl'
      'cache/main.out'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder -output-directory="cache"  "main.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
entering extended mode
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\size12.clo))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\utf8.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu)))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.def)))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hyphsubst.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty))))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\array.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.st
y
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\cite\cite.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\mathptmx.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype-pdftex.de
f) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.cfg))
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.aux)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\t1ptm.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
))
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.out)
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.out)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\mt-ptm.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omlztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omsztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omxztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ptm.fd) [1{D:/User/
Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Terence' on page 1 undefined on input line 111.
...

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omsptm.fd) [4]
[5]
Underfull \hbox (badness 3769) in paragraph at lines 289--289
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Estudo da im-ple-men-ta-▒▒o de
[6] [7] [8] [9]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 392--403

[10] [11]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 424--424
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 424--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Manuten▒▒o

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Usar o la-

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--426
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Manuten▒▒o

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 426--426
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 2012) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas de

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Tratamento

Underfull \hbox (badness 1953) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Cuidados di▒-

Underfull \hbox (badness 5637) in paragraph at lines 427--427
\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) rios apro-pri-a-
[12]
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.bbl
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1cmtt.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--11
\T1/cmtt/m/n/12 232273065 _ CAVERNA _ Digital _ -[]Sistema _ de _ Multiprojecao
 _ Estereoscopico _ Baseado _

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--11
\T1/cmtt/m/n/12 em _ Aglomerados _ de _ PCs _ para _ Aplicacoes _ Imersivas _ e
m _ Realidade _ Virtual / links /

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--32
[]$\T1/cmtt/m/n/12 http : / / marcelohsantos . com . br / aulas / downloads / 2
Semestre _ 2014 / novasmidias /
) [13]
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information){D:/User/Documents/latex/te
xmfs/install/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}{D:/User/Documents/latex/
texmfs/install/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/inst
all/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/i
nstall/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sftt1200.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs
/install/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/insta
ll/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fon
ts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on D:\ObjectBeautif
ier\monograph\proposal\cache\main.pdf (14 pages, 129387 bytes).
Transcript written on D:\ObjectBea
utifier\monograph\proposal\cache\main.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'cache/main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `Terence' on page 1 undefined on input line 111
  ...
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [refs.bib]
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 11 citation(s)
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex cache/main'...
Rule 'bibtex cache/main': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'cache/main.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'bibtex cache/main'
------------
For rule 'bibtex cache/main', running '&run_bibtex(  )' ...
------------
Running 'bibtex  "main"'
------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: abbrv.bst
Database file #1: refs.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'cache/main.aux'
      'cache/main.toc'
------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder -output-directory="cache"  "main.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
entering extended mode
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
...
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg)
...
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\cite\cite.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\mathptmx.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype-pdftex.de
f) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.cfg))
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.aux)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\t1ptm.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
))
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.out)
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.out)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\microtype\mt-ptm.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omlztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omsztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omxztmcm.fd)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ptm.fd) [1{D:/User/
Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [1]
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.toc) [2] [3]
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\omsptm.fd) [4]
[5]
Underfull \hbox (badness 3769) in paragraph at lines 289--289
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Estudo da im-ple-men-ta-▒▒o de
[6] [7] [8] [9]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 392--403

[10] [11]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 424--424
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 424--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Manuten▒▒o

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--425
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Usar o la-

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 425--426
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Manuten▒▒o

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 426--426
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas

Underfull \hbox (badness 2012) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Problemas de

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Tratamento

Underfull \hbox (badness 1953) in paragraph at lines 427--427
[]|\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) Cuidados di▒-

Underfull \hbox (badness 5637) in paragraph at lines 427--427
\T1/ptm/m/n/12 (+20) rios apro-pri-a-
[12]
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.bbl
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1cmtt.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--11
\T1/cmtt/m/n/12 232273065 _ CAVERNA _ Digital _ -[]Sistema _ de _ Multiprojecao
 _ Estereoscopico _ Baseado _

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--11
\T1/cmtt/m/n/12 em _ Aglomerados _ de _ PCs _ para _ Aplicacoes _ Imersivas _ e
m _ Realidade _ Virtual / links /

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--32
[]$\T1/cmtt/m/n/12 http : / / marcelohsantos . com . br / aulas / downloads / 2
Semestre _ 2014 / novasmidias /
) [13]
(D:\monograph\pro
posal\cache\main.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information){D:/User/Documents/latex/te
xmfs/install/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}{D:/User/Documents/latex/
texmfs/install/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/inst
all/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/i
nstall/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sftt1200.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs
/install/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/insta
ll/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fon
ts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on D:\ObjectBeautif
ier\monograph\proposal\cache\main.pdf (14 pages, 130737 bytes).
Transcript written on D:\ObjectBea
utifier\monograph\proposal\cache\main.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'cache/main.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [refs.bib]
Latexmk: All targets (cache/main.pdf) are up-to-date
# latex main.tex
# bibtex main.tex
# latex main.tex
# latex main.tex
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with TexLive and solved it by installing the approriate package

```
sudo dnf install texlive-hyphen-italian
```

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me:

```
initexmf --mklangs
initexmf -u
```

Source: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/136#issuecomment-392561637