# Babel: Warning about the non-existance of Vietnamese hyphenation patterns

Tags: babel, hyphenation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

results in this .log produced with TeXlive:

```
...texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/02/24 3.9q The Babel package

texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-vietnamese/vietnamese.ldf
Language: vietnamese 

texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2016/02/24 3.9q Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Vietnamese' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 36. ...
```

As there exist no Vietnamese hyphenation patterns (because there is no hyphenation in Vietnamese), they cannot be preloaded. How do I avoid the warning?

Comment: Does Vietnamese use hyphenation to begin with?

Comment: I had this problem with TexLive and solved it by installing the approriate package ```
sudo dnf install texlive-hyphen-italian
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for (babel) the language \`Portuguese'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365804/how-to-fix-the-warning-no-hyphenation-patterns-were-preloaded-for-babel-the-l)

Comment: @robertspierre No, not at all: There exists hyphenation in Portuguese, and hyphenation patterns exists, but neither is the case for Vietnamese. My question is: Babel wants to hyphenate  in a language which does not have any hyphenations - how to tell babel to not to try that?

Comment: @robertspierre The bug has been fixed: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2023-September/049480.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Karl Berry fixed this bug in September 2023, https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2023-September/049480.html:

> Until a hyph-utf8 update is released[...], I added the lines (r68317):

```
vietnamese zerohyph.tex
hebrew zerohyph.tex
```

> to texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/language.us, which (I hope) will
> cause a rebuild of the language files after the next update.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, Vietnamese doesn't use hyphenation, since all words are monosyllabic.

You can avoid the warning (and possible wrong hyphenation) with the help of `hyphsubst`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}

\begin{document}

Chào thế giới

\end{document}
```

Comment: I only need to (possibly) hyphenate some names, e.g. `Nguyen`, which seems to have more than one syllable, but I do not speak Vietnamese. Not hyphenating those names is probably a good approach. Would it make sense for `babel` to have "empty" hyphenation rules for Vietnamese?

Comment: @Burgmeister Yes, it would. And, yes, not hyphenating is better than doing it wrong.

Comment: As a native speaker, I can confirm that all native Vietnamese words are monosyllabic. Hyphenation would only be useful for scientific words that are transcribed from another language, but since there are too many conventions to write them (I can recall at least 4), probably one should best do manual hyphenating.