# Possible bug in babel-greek, TexLive 2014

Tags: texlive, babel

Apologies for bug reporting here, but thought I might as well. My current banner is:

```
$ pdflatex -version | grep 'TeX Live'
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
```

The problem seems to be described in [Printing sentence in ancient Greek - comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/comp.text.tex/ajGFiDqpvW0#!topic/comp.text.tex/ajGFiDqpvW0), and in my case stems from here: [Getting Texlive version in pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205210/getting-texlive-version-in-pdflatex); regardless of which example I try, say:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\gettexliveversion#1(#2 #3 #4#5#6#7#8)#9\relax{#4#5#6#7}
\edef\texliveversion{\expandafter\gettexliveversion\pdftexbanner\relax}
% \usepackage{unravel}

% [Printing sentence in ancient Greek - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/comp.text.tex/ajGFiDqpvW0#!topic/comp.text.tex/ajGFiDqpvW0)
% fail at step 16200 (16190)
% \unravel{
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\ifnum\texliveversion<2013
  \usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
% }

\listfiles

\begin{document}

The starting verse of the Iliad is
\begin{quotation}\greektext
Μῆνιν ἄειδε, θεά, Πηληιάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
\end{quotation}
and it's really great.

\end{document}
```

... it fails with:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `greek' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 44.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.50 ...\bbl@monogreek \bbl@monogreek=\l@monogreek
```

If I keep on pressing ENTER at each error, eventually it compiles a PDF, and the listfiles output is:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
   greek.ldf    2014/09/18 v1.9b Greek support for the babel system
  lgrenc.def    2013/12/02 v0.11.2 LGR Greek font encoding definitions
greek-fontenc.def    2013/11/28 v0.11 Common Greek font encoding definitions
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  lgrenc.dfu    2014/09/14 1.5 UTF-8 support for Greek
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
  lgrcmr.fd    2013/09/01 v1.0 Greek European Computer Regular
 ***********
```

The comp.text.tex thread actually mentions:

> Actually, to get this far I edited
>     `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/texmf-compat/tex/latex/greek.ldf`
>   replacing
>
> ```
> \ifx\l@monogreek\@undefined
>   \adddialect\@monogreek 0\fi
> \ifx\l@ancientgreek\@undefined
>   \adddialect\@ancientgreek 0\fi
> ```
>
> by
>
> ```
> \ifx\l@monogreek\@undefined
>   \adddialect\l@monogreek 0\fi
> \ifx\l@ancientgreek\@undefined
>   \adddialect\l@ancientgreek 0\fi
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The second version has `\l@monogreek` in the second line (for `\@monogreek`),
>   and a similar change in the fourth line.
>
> After the change my problems go away.

For me, that snippet is in `/media/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-greek/greek.ldf`, and contains:

```
...
\ProvidesLanguage{greek}
        [2014/09/18 v1.9b Greek support for the babel system]
%% File `babel-greek.dtx'
...
\ifx\l@greek\@undefined
  \@nopatterns{greek}
  \adddialect\l@greek 0\fi
\ifx\l@monogreek\@undefined
  \adddialect\@monogreek 0\fi
\ifx\l@ancientgreek\@undefined
  \adddialect\@ancientgreek 0\fi
```

Clearly, it should be `\adddialect\l@monogreek`, not `\adddialect\@monogreek` as it is; and indeed, when I make that change as well, the document compiles just fine.

---

The thing is this: I installed TexLive from scratch (`install-tl`), tried to compile the given MWE, it fails with given error - had to hack `babel-greek/greek.ldf` as described to get it to compile. So, there's either faulty code in `greek.ldf` and it's a bug -- or I miss some package, and Latex cannot tell me which with the usual "file not found" message. Since no one else can reproduce this error, it is probably not a bug - but how do I find what I am missing, then?

Comment: Isn't this off-topic? It is not, after all, a question. Why don't you report the bug? You apologise for reporting it here but you literally cannot report it here in the sense usually meant by 'reporting a bug'. You can report that you believe this is a bug here. You can report that this is a bug here. But you cannot report the bug here. To put this another way: what exactly are you looking for in an answer?

Comment: And what do I have to do to reproduce the bug? If I run your code as is, it compiles fine.

Comment: I can't confirm the 'bug' you described

Comment: I'd agree with the above comments and can't see the bug, but also note this is _nothing to do with TeX Live_. If there is a bug in a package it's an issue for the package maintainer(s): in this case, `babel` is handled by the LaTeX team so any issues should be reported to http://latex-project.org/bugs.html.

Comment: @all, thanks for the comments - I updated the post with a question: since none of you can reproduce the bug, it would have been pointless to report it as such - that means I'm probably missing a package; how do I find that I'm missing so I don't have to hack `greek.ldf` manually?

Comment: @sdaau I don't think the `.ldf` file is wrong here (I have `\ifx\l@monogreek\@undefined\adddialect\@monogreek 0\fi` and so on, and I think this looks right). What I do wonder is about file paths: have you got mismatched files. Can you post the part of your `.log` file which shows the various files being loaded so we can see the full paths?

Comment: Also, something is obviously up with your hyphenation patterns. Recent TeX Live systems simply build all of them into the format, but you don't seem to have that. What does the ID line for patterns in your `.log` say? I have `Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.`

Comment: Imho the ldf is wrong. But it doesn't lead to errors on systems where the greek hyphenation patterns are all loaded. It only bite people with missing patterns. Check your language.dat.

Comment: Thanks @JosephWright - I reverted `greek.ldf` to its original contents, and rebuilt the test in OP (so it now fails, and I keep pressing ENTER) - a full paste of the log file, tuned to the path given in OP, is here: http://pastebin.com/x2QMVSL0 ; the log file says "`Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.`" - this looks like it's the error! Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer - I did look via `less $(kpsewhich language.dat)`; and the full contents of that file as I have it are on http://pastebin.com/waaen1v2 ; nothing in there but `=usenglish` and `=american` ; this is likely the problem (related to what Babel says in log file). What can I do to add greek to this, now?

Comment: Depends on the location of the language.dat. If it is the autogenerated from texlive: Install with tlmgr more patterns (search for "hyphen"). If is is some local language.dat that you created then rename it and rebuild the formats and check what happens.BTW: I sent Günter a note about the error in greek.ldf.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it. The thing is - what I usually do if I install a new TexLive version, I install the minimal packages, and then try to tex my docs and add packages until they compile - so obviously there was some missing stuff here. Here is a log of what I did to get it properly working (without hacks).

As pointed out in comments: the first key thing is that my log said:

```
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
```

... and this is, typically, far too little. This can be confirmed by inspecting `kpsewhich language.dat`, which in my case, had only these uncommented lines:

```
%
english         hyphen.tex  % do not change!
=usenglish
=USenglish
=american
% ...
%
dumylang        dumyhyph.tex    %for testing a new language.
nohyphenation   zerohyph.tex    %a language with no patterns at all.
```

So these `hyphenation patterns for 2 languages` reported, may have been `english` and `dummylang` - I wouldn't know.

So the question is what to do to add hyphenation for Greek; as @UlrikeFischer hinted, this "depends on the location of the language.dat" - and I apparently use the autogenerated, not a local one:

```
$ kpsewhich language.dat
/media/texlive/2014/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat
```

So, I did search for "hyphen" using `tlmgr search --global --file hyphen`, and installed what I thought was interesting like this:

```
$ tlmgr install hyph-utf8 hyphen-ancientgreek hyphen-greek 
...
[1/2, ??:??/??:??] install: hyphen-ancientgreek [17k]
[2/2, 00:00/00:00] install: hyphen-greek [717k]
...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/media/texlive/2014/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat" ...
...
```

Now when I checked the `language.dat`, it had this at end:

```
...
% 
dumylang        dumyhyph.tex    %for testing a new language.
nohyphenation   zerohyph.tex    %a language with no patterns at all.
% from hyphen-ancientgreek:
ancientgreek loadhyph-grc.tex
ibycus ibyhyph.tex
% from hyphen-greek:
monogreek loadhyph-el-monoton.tex
greek loadhyph-el-polyton.tex
=polygreek
```

Neat - but the example still didn't compile! So, I tried:

```
tlmgr install --reinstall babel-greek
```

Nope. Then I tried as per hints in [No hyphenation patterns were loaded for the language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/no-hyphenation-patterns-were-loaded-for-the-language):

```
fmtutil --all
```

Nope - example still didn't compile. Then I tried as per: [TeX Frequently Asked Questions -- Using a new language with Babel / question label "newlang"](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-newlang):

```
$ texconfig hyphen latex
texconfig hyphen is no longer supported, because manual edits of
language.dat (or language.def) will be overwritten by the new TeX Live
package manager, tlmgr, which regenerates those configuration files as
needed upon package changes.  Thus, to add or remove hyphenation
patterns, the recommended method is to use tlmgr to add or remove the
appropriate package.

If you need to make manual additions, you can edit the files
language-local.dat and language-local.def under TEXMFLOCAL.  Further
information with tlmgr --help and at http://tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html.

Exiting.
```

So that's a no-go. So then I tried this:

```
$ fmtutil --byhyphen language.dat
fmtutil: no format depends on hyphen file `/tmp/language.dat'.
```

Ah, so here it refers to current working directory? Let's throw in an absolute path:

```
$ fmtutil --byhyphen `kpsewhich language.dat` 2>&1 | tee fmtutil.log
...
$ grep 'language\|installed' fmtutil.log
...
  50 for language 6
  18 for language 5
  148 for language 4
  97 for language 3
  2 for language 1
  181 for language 0
fmtutil: ~/.texlive2014/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt installed.
  50 for language 6
  18 for language 5
  148 for language 4
  97 for language 3
  2 for language 1
  181 for language 0
fmtutil: ~/.texlive2014/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt installed.
...
```

Ah, so it looks like now the hyphenation patterns for all newly installed languages are now reconstructed? But the example *still* didn't compile?

Finally, I enter almost by accident this:

```
/tmp$ kpsewhich pdflatex.fmt
./pdflatex.fmt
/tmp$ rm pdflatex.fmt 
/tmp$ kpsewhich pdflatex.fmt
/tmp$
```

... and realize that I have a `pdflatex.fmt` in my current working directory `/tmp`, probably generated by `fmtutil --byfmt pdflatex` when I was messing with this earlier. So I delete this `/tmp/pdflatex.fmt`, then `kpsewhich` cannot find a `pdflatex.fmt` anymore - and then FINALLY the `pdflatex test.tex` completes compiling without an error; with the log now being:

```
...
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 6 languages loaded.
... 
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
   greek.ldf    2014/09/18 v1.9b Greek support for the babel system
  lgrenc.def    2013/12/02 v0.11.2 LGR Greek font encoding definitions
  lgrenc.dfu    2014/09/14 1.5 UTF-8 support for Greek
greek-fontenc.def    2013/11/28 v0.11 Common Greek font encoding definitions
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
  lgrcmr.fd    2013/09/01 v1.0 Greek European Computer Regular
 ***********
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 26870 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

And hopefully, this is now installed as it should be for TexLive 2014.