# Error when using Greek babel, mparhack and \pagenumbering{roman}

Tags: page-numbering, babel, greek, roman-numerals

Using:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
```

... I compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} %% A
\usepackage{mparhack}             %% B
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}             %% C
Testing

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

... which triggers the following error upon `pdflatex test.tex`:

```
! Use of \\@lipsum doesn't match its definition.
\text@command #1->\def \reserved@a {
                                    #1}\ifx \reserved@a \@empty \let \check@...
l.12 \end{document}

? 
! Unbalanced write command.
<write> \string \mph@setcol {ii:\thepage }{
                                           \string \mph@nr }
l.12 \end{document}

? X
```

Interestingly, this error appears *only* when all three: A, B, and C are present; it doesn't occur if we replace, say, A with `\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}` (if you delete the old .aux file first before recompiling). (<sub>Note: in my original doc, I actually got `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line ...` appearing at `\mph@outputpage@hook` which is from `mparhack`; but similarly, that error appeared first only after adding `greek` to `babel`</sub>)

So this seems to be a specific error occuring when Greek `babel`, `mparhack` and `\pagenumbering{roman}` interact. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is quite subtle and `lipsum` is not really involved.

### Analysis of the problem

The `mparhack` package makes some annotations in the `.aux` files, using

```
\newcommand*\mph@outputpage@hook{%
    \bgroup
    \advance\c@page\m@ne
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\mph@setcol{ii:\thepage}{\string\mph@nr}%
    }%
    \egroup
}
```

and the problem starts here: with `\pagenumbering{roman}` the command `\thepage` means `\roman{page}` and, when Greek is used, the command `\@roman` that's used by `\roman` doesn't survive `\write`, because it now contains `\textlatin` which is not fully expandable.

The error involves `\\@lipsum` because this macro happens to be stored in `\reserved@a`, but it's just a symptom, not the disease.

### The cure

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}     
\usepackage{mparhack}                 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\mph@outputpage@hook{%
    \bgroup
    \let\textlatin\@firstofone % make \textlatin a no-op
    \advance\c@page\m@ne
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\mph@setcol{ii:\thepage}{\string\mph@nr}%
    }%
    \egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}                 
Testing

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

This successfully removes any attempt to expand the original `\textlatin` when writing the annotation. The redefinition is performed in a group, so the meaning of `\textlatin` will be restored as soon as `\egroup` is scanned. In the `.aux` file you'll find

```
\mph@setcol{ii:i}{\mph@nr}
```

which should be correct, because `ii:i` is used only as a unique label.

### Further problems

In case the `twocolumn` option is used, the problem reappears in a different form; a possible solution is to patch also `\mph@setcol` and `\mph@check`, because in this case it's not really possible to remove `\textlatin` from the annotation, so we remove it when `\mph@setcol` and `\mph@check` are executed. Adding a group around them is not a problem, because both only do global assignments anyway.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{mparhack}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% this is the hack for one column output
\patchcmd\mph@outputpage@hook
  {\bgroup}
  {\bgroup\let\textlatin\@firstofone}
  {}{}
% this is the hack for two column output
\pretocmd\mph@setcol{\bgroup\let\textlatin\@firstofone}{}{}
\apptocmd\mph@setcol{\egroup}{}{}
\pretocmd\mph@check{\bgroup\let\textlatin\@firstofone}{}{}
\apptocmd\mph@check{\egroup}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Testing

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @egreg - I would never had guessed this had anything to with annotations in `.aux` files; cheers!

Comment: Note that this hack introduces some breakage with the `todonotes` package, which can be fixed by patching additionally patching `\mph@ifundef@or@smaller` - see my [post below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207242/error-when-using-greek-babel-mparhack-and-pagenumberingroman/213467#213467)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got something, but I'm not sure it's correct - so more erudite responses will be appreciated. By using package `{trace}`, I compared the trace outputs for the correct `[english]` and the problematic `[greek,english]` options for babel. Both variants end up in this stack trace:

```
\mph@outputpage@hook ->\bgroup \advance \c@page \m@ne \immediate \write \@auxout {\string \mph@setcol {ii:\thepage }{\string \mph@nr }}\egroup

  \thepage ->\csname @roman\endcsname \c@page
```

At this point, the `\@roman` command is called; in the `[english]`-only case, it is:

```
\@roman #1->\romannumeral #1
```

... but in the `[greek,english]` case, it is:

```
\@roman #1->\expandafter \textlatin \expandafter {\romannumeral #1}
```

... and `\textlatin` calls `\text@command #1->\def \reserved@a {#1}...` where `#1<-i` (the roman numeral `i` for page number 1); however it turns out in this case `\reserved@a ->\\@lipsum` somehow, and so we'd get, I guess `\@lipsum{i}` trying to execute, which indeed is wrong.

I read a bit through `texdoc babel-greek`, and it seems `\textlatin` is to ensure switching to a latin language font/encoding; I am guessing that apparently `\@roman` is redefined by `babel-greek` simply to ensure that the engine is in "latin text" mode before trying to typeset roman numerals, which makes sense - but makes the unfortunate interaction in this case.

My use for `[greek,...]{babel}` is mostly to ensure fonts/encoding for correct display of μ in `siunitx` and the like (related: [Possible bug in babel-greek, TexLive 2014](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205222/possible-bug-in-babel-greek-texlive-2014)); I will not be using sections of greek text. Thus, the likelihood for typesetting roman numerals while in greek text mode is very low, so I thought: why not redefine the `\@roman` command back to what it was? Here `texdef` helps:

```bash
$ texdef -t latex -s @roman
% latex.ltx, line 1850:
\def\@roman#1{\romannumeral #1}
```

... and so, the fixed MWE that works now is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} %% A
\usepackage{mparhack}             %% B
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\traceon
\pagenumbering{roman}             %% C
% latex.ltx, line 1850:         % fix
\makeatletter                   % fix
\def\@roman#1{\romannumeral #1} % fix
\makeatother                    % fix

Testing

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Redefining `\@roman` to be the original is wrong: if Greek is the main language, your page numbers will use iota for ‘i’ and chi for ‘x’.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but the answer does make clear that it solves the problem, given that the use of Greek is limited and won't use `roman` numerals.