# Failure with [greek] babel and lastpage, \frontmatter?

Tags: compiling, babel, preamble

I have a large document, for which I wanted to generate "precompiled headers" ([TikZ's externalization and mylatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19403/tikzs-externalization-and-mylatex) (note, \jobname should be the same)) and thought I'd use `mylatexformat` for it ([ultrafast pdflatex with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling)). That ended in failure, so in trying to derive an MWE to post, I think I stumbled upon a more precise problem.

The structure looks something like this:

> **`setup/_preamble.tex`**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{cmap}% (causes pdflatex: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced. with -ini/mylatexformat)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % ok
% \usepackage[greek,english]{babel} % BAD with lastpage (+\frontmatter)!!!!
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lastpage}
```

> **`test.tex`**

```
%% This is the file `test.tex'

\input{setup/_preamble.tex}

\csname endofdump\endcsname%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\clearpage

\section{Something}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

If I compile this with `pdflatex test.tex`, it compiles fine.

I "compile" the `test.fmt` file like this:

```
$ pdflatex -ini -jobname="test" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "test.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (INITEX)
...
Beginning to dump on file test.fmt
 (preloaded format=test 2015.2.18)
31400 strings of total length 611843
661162 memory locations dumped; current usage is 654&652915
28229 multiletter control sequences
\font\nullfont=nullfont
\font\OMX/cmex/m/n/10=cmex10
...
20 words of pdfTeX memory
8 indirect objects
No pages of output.

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Then I build the `.pdf` file using the precompiled `.fmt` file like this (I don't include the `%&test` comment as the first line of the `test.tex` file, but instead I specify it on the command line):

```
$ pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 "&test" test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
...
==============================================================================
JOB NAME         : "test"
CUSTOMISED FORMAT: "test"
PRELOADED FILES:
setup/_preamble.tex
    book.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
...
==============================================================================
(mylatexformat)Info: start reading document "test"
(mylatexformat)      on input line 6. (\endofdump)
==============================================================================
(/media/disk/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
...
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 41826 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

So the MWE as-is works with the "precompiled" `.fmt` file.

Now, if you comment the `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, and uncomment the `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` line in `setup/_preamble.tex`: the `.fmt` file can be built successfully, BUT building the `.pdf` fails with:

```
$ pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 "&test" test.tex
...
==============================================================================
JOB NAME         : "test"
CUSTOMISED FORMAT: "test"
PRELOADED FILES:
setup/_preamble.tex
...
==============================================================================
(mylatexformat)Info: start reading document "test"
(mylatexformat)      on input line 6. (\endofdump)
==============================================================================
(/media/disk/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
...
(/media/disk/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviati
ons.cfg)<<ot1.cmap>><<ot1tt.cmap>><<t1.cmap>> 
AED: lastpage setting LastPage
[1{/media/disk/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
]
./test.tex:16: Use of \\@lipsum doesn't match its definition.
\text@command #1->\def \reserved@a {
                                    #1}\ifx \reserved@a \@empty \let \check@...
l.16 \end{document}

?
```

... and the failure of `\lipsum` is, I guess, just a symptom of some other problem.

However, the `.pdf` build will succeed with precompiled `.fmt` and `[greek,]{babel}` if either `\usepackage{lastpage}` (in `_preamble.tex`) is commented; OR if `\frontmatter` (in `test.tex`) is commented?

And after this, I discovered that the `.pdf` build will fail even without using precompiled `.fmt` file (i.e. just with `pdflatex test.tex`) - even if in my original doc, I never got an error like this, before I started messing with `.fmt` files ?! (Although, I should note, the error I get in my original doc is not expressed as an error with `\lipsum`, the error message is different)

What am I doing wrong - and how can I get this set of packages to build with a precompiled `.fmt` file without an error?

(PS: may be related to [Possible bug in babel-greek, TexLive 2014](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205222/possible-bug-in-babel-greek-texlive-2014) - as it was also a problem with a `.fmt` file there, but I'm not sure).

Comment: You probably have an old version of `lipsum`; as far as I know, it has been corrected to avoid using `\roman`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out this is the exact same problem solved by the answer by @egreg in [Error when using Greek babel, mparhack and \pagenumbering{roman}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207242/error-when-using-greek-babel-mparhack-and-pagenumberingroman/207267#207267). Here too, `[greek,]{babel}` redefines `\thepage` to use the unexpandable `\textlatin` - but the problem here occurs because `{lastpage}` wants to write `\thepage` into the `.aux` file, through its function/macro `\lastpage@putl@bel`.

So one solution is to add this to the `setup/_preamble.tex`:

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
\makeatletter
\let\oldlastpage@putl@bel\lastpage@putl@bel
\renewcommand*\lastpage@putl@bel{%
  \bgroup
  \let\textlatin\@firstofone % make \textlatin a no-op
  \oldlastpage@putl@bel%
  \egroup
}
\makeatother
```

... and then, seemingly, all works fine for `[greek,english]{babel}` - even when generating and using the precompiled `.fmt` file.

So, after all, this had not much to do with `mylatexformat` as such (so I'll have to still look for an MWE to demonstrate the problem I still have `:)`)

Btw, I saw this by using package `{trace}` in `test.tex` like this:

```
\input{setup/_preamble.tex}

\csname endofdump\endcsname%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{trace}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\clearpage

\section{Something}
\lipsum[1-5]

\traceon % trace only the \end{document} part
\end{document}
```

... and then comparing the `.log` files (for `[greek,english]{babel}` run vs. `[english]{babel}` one) in `meld`.