# unable to get hyphenation patterns for german on fedora

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation, german

I run the following file with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}
Tach auch
\end{document}
```

and got the errors:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./x.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `German (trad. orthography)' into the forma
t.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 58.

)))
No file x.aux.
[1{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./x.aux)
 )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on x.pdf (1 page, 11102 bytes).
Transcript written on x.log.
```

I already saw the question: [No hyphenation patterns were loaded for the language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/no-hyphenation-patterns-were-loaded-for-the-language)

and I already did `sudo fmtutil --all -sys` on my system.

From my distro the following packages with "german" in its names were installed:

texlive-babel-german.noarch                         8:svn47192-25.fc29                     @updates
texlive-datetime2-german.noarch                     8:svn45800-25.fc29                     @updates
texlive-german.noarch                               8:svn42428-25.fc29                     @updates
texlive-glossaries-german.noarch                    8:svn35665.1.0-25.fc29                 @updates

If I cahnge to `ngerman` I got more warnings/errors. But I want to stay for "old german".

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1595165

So first uninstall the package:
`texlive-hyphen-german.noarch`

Then remove `rm ~/.texlive2018/ -rf`

then install again:
`sudo dnf install texlive-hyphen-german.noarch`

Now it works!